# InnerHTML append instead of replacing

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using this code to update a `div` with an AJAX request

```
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else { // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("some_id").innerHTML += xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://example.com/");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'utf8');
xmlhttp.send();
```

Everything works fine, the problem is that when the `div` with id `some_id` has a lot of content in it i can see the content disappearing and then appearing updated after the AJAX request has been executed.

I think that it's because

```
document.getElementById("some_id").innerHTML += xmlhttp.responseText;
```

Is deleting and replacing the `innerHTML` of the `div` with the previous `innerHTML` plus the new content, resulting in a `previous content → blank → updated content` behaviour.

Is there a way to *append* the new content to the `div` instead of replacing its whole content with the new one?

Comment: are you using jquery or native javascript?

Comment: try to add child element instead of replacing the entire html

Comment: @Raghu I'm using both, but a pure javascript solution would be better for me

Comment: theoretically you should never see the flicker, because the rendering is only done after the script's callback ends. Have you got particularly complicated HTML?

Comment: @BackSlash if you are using jQuery, you should *never* use `innerHTML` directly, because it won't remove the event handlers. Use jQuery's `.html` option instead, or you will get massive memory leaks (yes, they do exist in JavaScript)

Comment: @Dave Yes, it's a joomla site and the template has a lot of nested divs

Comment: Sounds like you might be making the rendering engine cry. Try to limit the amount of code which is on the page at once. Some sites replace content which is above/below the viewport with large empty divs for this reason (keeping the actual content alive as a DOM known only to the JavaScript. i.e. not contained within the document)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming that `htmlhttp.responseText` is a node:

```
document.getElementById("some_id").appendChild(xmlhttp.responseText);
```

If you have only a string of HTML (which seems likely), then:

```
var newElement = document.createElement('div');
newElement.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
document.getElementById("some_id").appendChild(newElement);
```

On the other hand, if you must append new elements from a string:

```
// getting a reference to the relevant element we're adding to:
var container = document.getElementById("some_id"),
    // creating a new element to contain the 'xmlhttp.responseText'
    newElement = document.createElement('div');
// setting the innerHTML of the 'newElement' to whatever 'xmlhttp.responseText' is:
newElement.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;

/* (repeatedly) removing the firstChild, and appending it to the 'container',
   of the 'newElement' until it's empty: */
while (newElement.firstChild) {
    container.appendChild(newElement.firstChild);
}
// removing the now empty 'newElement':
newElement.parentNode.removeChild(newElement);
```

References:

- [`Node.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild).

Comment: And what if it's a bunch of nodes?

Comment: Then you can either iterate over each of those nodes and use `appendChild()` repeatedly, or wrap them within one node and append *that* node. Without seeing (an example of) what's in your `xmlhttp.responseText` variable it's very hard to answer specifically to address your use-case.

Comment: Saw the update, what if i _must_ append to the current div without creating a new one?

Comment: `htmlhttp.responseText` is most probably a string.

Comment: @SalmanA: yes, that's why I added the second code block following the phrase 'if you have only a string of HTML (which seems likely)'.

Comment: @BackSlash: then *give an example of what you're working with*.

Comment: @DavidThomas This is the example. I want to add content to a div without creating new elements.

Comment: @DavidThomas Your last example worked perfectly, but i had to add a check for `newElement.parentNode!=undefined` before `newElement.parentNode.removeChild(newElement);`, it was giving me _Unable to access removeChild() on a non object_. Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

You could use [`Element.insertAdjacentHTML()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML).

> insertAdjacentHTML() parses the specified text as HTML or XML and **inserts the resulting nodes into the DOM tree at a specified position**. It does not reparse the element it is being used on and thus it does not corrupt the existing elements inside the element. This, and avoiding the extra step of serialization make it much faster than direct innerHTML manipulation.

I guess you would do

```
const div = document.getElementById("some_id");
div.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', xmlhttp.responseText);;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
old_html = document.getElementById("some_id").innerHTML;
document.getElementById("some_id").innerHTML = old_html+xmlhttp.responseText;
```

Comment: How is this different from mine?