# Printing rows count above each table

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp, record-count

I need your help and assistant in viewing the number of rows on each printed table at the top of it.

I am using the below code to get the rows count:

```
    function count()
    {

    var tables = document.getElementsByClassName("tablesorter");
    var rows;
    for (var i = 0; i < tables.length; i++) {
      rows = tables[i].rows.length-1;
      alert(rows);
      span.innerHTML = rows;
    }
```

Currently the rows number are displayed in alerts and I want the number of the rows to be displayed in the html. I am printing the tables through while loop based on the retrieved values from the DB and they are having the same class and name. The class name is tablesorter and the id is detailsid .

I tried to print the number of the rows in the span, however it prints only above the first table. It prints first 22 and then it was overwrited with 30 where the 30 should be printed above the second table. Here is my code for printing

```
<%
while (rs.next())
        {

        count=0;
        name=rs.getString("name");   

        if (!(subcategory_name1).equals(temp_subcategory_name) )
            {
            i=0;                         
%>
<span id='span'></span>
<table class="tablesorter" id="detailsTable" width="80%">
<b>
<font style="font-size: 9pt" face="Arial" color="#162650"><%=category_name1%> / <%=subcategory_name1%> </font>
</b>
           <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>No.</th>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
<%
}
%>
        <tbody>
<tr>
            <td><%=i%></td>
            <td align=left><%=name%></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Kindly assit me in printing the number of the rows above each table

Comment: `span.innerHTML = rows;` You are overwriting your span innerHtml in the loop instead of appending, FWIW.

Comment: Sample : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18539992/innerhtml-append-instead-of-replacing

Comment: why not use JSTL? you can do this simply..

Comment: appending is not the issue. The issue is that the no of rows will not be printed above each table. The first table will have the rows number and the others will not have any value

Answer (score 2):

As i can see your code you are first assigning the

**rows = tables[i].rows.length-1;**

and then using it to assign rows to span so every time it changes it will be reflected in all the spans

so you can directly assign the value `tables[i].rows.length-1;` to the span

no need to use a variable row

Comment: The problem is that the span value will be shown only once in the report above the first table only... the other tables will not have any value above them. First the alert will show that 20 rows and it will print 20. Then, an alert will be shown for 30 and the number of rows which was 20 above the first table will change to 30. I want the 20 to be above the first table. Then 30 to be shown on the second table

Comment: would you mind sharing your code so that i can have a little insight of your code i think i can solve the issue but first i need to know the problem clearly