# Adding a textbox to div without losing values

Tags: javascript, html

i've a div container and a button. Whenever i click the button, an empty textbox is added to the div. Now, my problem is whenever i click the button, the textbox is added, but the values of all others are removed.

The function is made like this:

```
function addTextBox() {
    document.getElementById("txtList").innerHTML += "<input type='text'>";
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle for your issue ?

Comment: Post the html too

Comment: What do you mean the value of all others because here you don't append the value ?

Comment: What "values of all others"?  It's not really clear what you're describing.

Comment: I think you should take a look at `document.createDocumentFragment`,  `document.createElement` and `document.appendChild`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18539992/innerhtml-append-instead-of-replacing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening under the hood here is that when you append the DOM as text using `innerHTML` you are simply rewriting that section of HTML. Editing your textList `innerHTML` will execute a new paint of that element and all information will be parsed again. This means you loose your user interaction.

To update your DOM elements successfully there are methods which enable you to do that. namely `document.createElement` and `document.appendChild`.

By appending the DOM element as opposed to concatenating the `innerHTML(text)` your are forcing a limited paint of the specific area. This leaves the rest of the DOM in tact.

**Your code here**

```
function addTextBox() {
    document.getElementById("txtList").innerHTML += "<input type='text'>";
}
```

**Becomes more like the following**

```
function addTextBox() {
    var textEl = document.getElementById("txtList");
    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.type = 'text';

    textEl.appendChild(input);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it help you:

```
var child = document.createElement('input')
 document.getElementById("txtList").appendChild(child);
```

Comment: innerHTML removes old content

Answer (score 2):

You could achieve the same thing as the snippet below:

```js
function addTextBox() {
    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.type = "text"
    document.getElementById("txtList").appendChild(input);
}

document.getElementById("addTxtBoxBtn").addEventListener("click",addTextBox);
```

```html
<input type="button" id="addTxtBoxBtn" value="add TextBox"/>
<div id="txtList">
</div>
```

> Why you can't achieve the same thing with innerHTML?

This happens [because](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML):

> The Element.innerHTML property sets or gets the **HTML syntax** describing the element's descendants.

While the `value`of an ipunt element is not an attribute of the element but a property (please have a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement#Properties)).

If you want to check it in action, please try the following snippet:

```js
function addTextBox() {
    var txtList = document.getElementById("txtList");
    console.log(txtList.innerHTML);
    txtList.innerHTML += "<input type='text'/>" ;
}

document.getElementById("addTxtBoxBtn").addEventListener("click",addTextBox);
```

```html
<input type="button" id="addTxtBoxBtn" value="add TextBox"/>
<div id="txtList">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you change append to `innerHTML` as a string, another string gets created (they are immutable). Browser than has to re-render the whole thing.

The other answers show `appendChild`, but since in your original question you used a string, maybe you want to keep doing so. If that's the case, you can use **`insertAdjacentHTML`** with `'beforeend'` as first argument.

```
document
  .getElementById('button')
  .addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.getElementById('txtList')
      .insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<input type="text">');
  });
```

[JSBin link is here.](http://jsbin.com/humuhimiwo/edit?html,js,output)